# Interpolation methods for prediction of water pollution

Tags: multivariate-analysis, interpolation

I have the following problem - I have ran MIKE11 software to compute the c(x,t) = concentration of pollutant in point x on a river (1D case) considering a pollution scenario where quantity q of pollutant at concentration c0 is thrown on the river at location x0. So, by varying x0, q, c0, x, t and running MIKE, I collected a number of 4 millions values of the function

> c = f(x,t,x0,q,c0)

so a function with 5 variables. So I need now to interpolate this function and I was considering to do spline multivariate interpolation. Are there other alternatives of doing this and what advantages/disadvantages could have.
For example I have read about Kriging,  inverse distance weighting, etc. - but are these methods good candidates for this problem?

Thank you
Regards